# HTML encoding in the alt attribute

Tags: html, validation

Why is it that `&#187;` valid for an alt atribute but `&raquo;` is not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on your doctype. In HTML 4 and 5, using named entities like `&raquo;` is perfectly valid. However, in XHTML you must use numbered entities like `&#187;` - most named entities are invalid, except for `&quot;`, `&apos;`, `&lt;`, `&gt;` and `&amp;`.

Note: the alt tag is irrelevant in this case, it allows the same textual content as outside of HTML tags.

Simplest solution in my opinion: switch to the HTML5 doctype - `<!DOCTYPE html>`. It forces standards modes in all browsers, is future proof and is dead simple to remember.

Comment: Interestingly the site this appeared in is HTML5

Comment: In that case maybe it's a bug in the HTML5 validator; I believe it's still in beta at the moment. HTML5 itself is still changing regularly.

Comment: @Toby don't trust what's written behind the hood, trust the specifications.

Comment: I just checked the [HTML5 spec for the img element](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-img-element) and couldn't see anything specifying the format of alt text.

Comment: @Oddant there is an argument though that in practice you need to trust how the browsers implement it - in an ideal world though, yes I would agree.